# SIGSEGV while reading file using file descriptor

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, file-descriptor

I'm trying to read file using file descriptor. The file descriptor is correct, so, the file is open correctly. The error is given when the program reads the last line

This is the code:

```
void readFile(char* filePath){
int fd,i=0;
char *c= NULL;
int read=1;
fd = open(filePath, O_RDONLY );
char **config;
config=(char**)malloc(4 * sizeof(char*));

if(fd<0){
    printf("Error");
} else {
    while (read==1){
        c=readLine(fd);

        if(*c=='\0'){
            read=0;
        }else{
            config[i]=(char*) malloc(sizeof(char));
            strcpy(config[i], c);
            i++;
        }
    }
    close(fd);
}

}

char *readLine(int fd){
 char character;
 char *array= malloc(1);
 unsigned int siz=1;


 while (read(fd, &character, 1) > 0 && character!='\n'){
     array=realloc(array, siz + 1);
     array[siz - 1]=character;
     siz ++;
 }
 array[siz - 1]='\0';
 return array;
```

Comment: `config[i]=(char*) malloc(sizeof(char));` gives you just enough space to store a terminating null.  strcpy into that location is almost guaranteed to produce undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The program has several flaws, including not freeing dynamically allocated memory (that returned by `readline` for example).

However, what is preventing the program to run at least is the lack of space of each of the `config[i]` locations. You just reserve space for one character `malloc(sizeof(char))`, but you have to reserve space for the whole string that afterwards is copied, plus the ending `'\0'`: `malloc(strlen(c) + 1)`. Also, take into account that using `strlen`, `strcpy`, etc. expects the string to contain non-binary data, and may fail with different encodings, etc.

Another solution would be to just assign `config[i]` to the returned `c` string, and later freeing it when freeing `config`. You would avoid the copy of the string.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it was a big mistake! Problem solved!